# research question semantics for logistic regression

Tags: logistic-regression

Is this wording appropriate for running a logistic regression? I am still understanding the difference between probabilities and likelihood so want to ensure I am correct:

Holding income constant, do people working in construction have a lower likelihood of being happy compared to people working in offices?

I went down a mini rabbit-hole re-watching vids breaking down logistic regression but it made me a little more confused. Because the s-curve has probability on the y-axis, but I think the final logistic reg model ranges from -infinity to +infinity?